# Switching tabs in active Tool Window in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

In Intellij, is there any key mapping to switch between tabs in an active tool window? E.g. I in the Debug tool window you have tabs such as `Deployment`, `Server`, `Output`, `Frames`, `Variables` and you can even configure them to be nested. e.g have `Frames` and `Output` as subtabs in `Server` tab. Is there any key combination to switch between those tabs similarly to switching between `Tool Windows and Editor` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `Alt + down arrow` opens a popup to select a tool tab in the focused panel (just like `Ctrl + Tab` does for editor views).
- `Alt + right/left arrow` selects the next/previous tool/editor tab.

Comment: `Alt + down arrow` didn't work for me, maybe because I use KDE keymap. But `Alt + right/left arrow` combined with `Tab` to switch between the nested tabs did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

On macos `ctrl + ↓` works for me - it does "Main menu | Window | Active Tool Window | Show List of Tabs"

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205972224/comments/360000910300